# When to use MergeAttribute over Attributes.Add

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, tagbuilder

When using TagBuilder one can use `TagBuilder.Attributes.Add(..)` or `TagBuilder. MergeAttribute(..)` to add attributes to the HTML element under construction:

```
TagBuilder formBuilder = new TagBuilder("form");
formBuilder.Attributes.Add("method", "get");
formBuilder.Attributes.Add("action", url);

TagBuilder buttonBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
buttonBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", "submit");
buttonBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", buttonText);
```

But how are the two different and when should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: As far as I can tell, they do the same... From MSDN (for the MergeAttribute-method): "Adds an attribute to the tag by using the specified key/value pair.". This pretty much looks the same as adding them through the Attributes-property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By looking at the `TagBuilder` with dotPeek, I can see that Attributes is an SortedDictionary

From ctor:

```
this.Attributes = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Calling Add on a SotredSet ends out calling an internal function AddIfNotPresent(item)

```
public bool Add(T item)
{
  return this.AddIfNotPresent(item);
}
```

This means that `Attributes.Add` is the same as calling MergeAttribute without setting `replaceExisting == true`.

```
   public void MergeAttribute(string key, string value, bool replaceExisting)
    {
      ...

      if (!replaceExisting && this.Attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        return;
      this.Attributes[key] = value;
    }
```

So my advice will be to use MergeAttribute over Add and always specify replaceExisting for readability and to make sure not to have unexpected outcomes.